# Reduce < along axis 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of pairs of ints. I'd like to reduce each pair using <, but `np.less.reduce(..., axis=1)` which I expected to work, doesn't:

```
>>> np.less.reduce(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 1]]), axis=1)
array([False, False])
```

I wanted the result `array([True, False])`. This surprised me, seeing that `add.reduce` (yes, I know that can be just `sum(...)`) does what I expect:

```
>>> np.add.reduce(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 1]]), axis=1)
array([3, 4])
```

What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing

```py
np.less.reduce([1,2])
```

it returns `False`, so less.reduce does not work the way you want it to here.

Why not simply:

```py
arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 1]])
np.less(arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
```